# How many build options are there in Nim

Tags: nim-lang

When you build an app in Nim, to compile in default mode (debug), you do `nim c <file>`. For release mode: `nim c -d:release <file>`. I heard on the internet that `nim c -d:danger` increases performance.

1. May I know why `-d:danger` increases performance, what is it?
2. How many of similar ones are there?

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [Nim documentation](https://nim-lang.org/documentation.html) in the *Other* section there's a link to the [Compiler user guide](https://nim-lang.org/docs/nimc.html). Here you can see different switches, and the `-d:foo` ones are said to be *"compile time define pragmas"*. Further down in that document you can find [Additional compilation switches](https://nim-lang.org/docs/nimc.html#additional-compilation-switches) which may help.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is basically "What flags for the compiler are there?"

For general building, nothing, release and danger are the three modes.

For every other kind of flag, there is the documentation section Grzegorz linked to.

As to why -d:danger is faster: It simply disables certain runtime checks that'll throw exceptions normally.
Which are a whole bunch of asserts.

```
let x = 100
assert x > 200
echo x
```

This for example will compile and run without error under -d:danger because it disables the asserts.
That makes things faster, but also may result in buggy outcomes.

Answer (score 0):

The option -d:danger compiles the code without any runtime checks like overflow, range, and array index checks.

You can find a short summary of a few useful options at https://nimprogrammingbook.com/book/nimprogramming_rouge_molokai.html#_launching_the_compiler_and_running_the_program

-d:lto can be useful.

All the available options should be explained in much detail in https://nim-lang.org/docs/nimc.html